# Not able to install BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7) required by cloud_firestore

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I have tried almost everything. I've used vpn to install , I've tried downgrading cocoapods . Ive tried different versions of cloud_firestore too.It works well on android but there's something wrong with firebase because same problem is occurring in Firebase Auth package too
nothing seems to work

Steps to Reproduce

Create a new project and add latest cloud_firestore package
Run without debugging on an iOS emulator
Build will be failed with following error

**Logs**

issue starts from here

```
Downloading dependencies

           -> Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
            > Git download
            > Git download
                $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git
                /var/folders/35/7c585fqj58s1xtl93svqy_xh0000gn/T/d20200731-5606-i9uho2 --template=
              $ /usr/bin/git -C /var/folders/35/7c585fqj58s1xtl93svqy_xh0000gn/T/d20200731-5606-i9uho2
checkout
--quiet 1c2769383f027befac5b75b6cedd25daf3bf4dcf

           [!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
           [!] /usr/bin/git -C /var/folders/35/7c585fqj58s1xtl93svqy_xh0000gn/T/d20200731-5606-i9uho2
checkout
--quiet 1c2769383f027befac5b75b6cedd25daf3bf4dcf

           fatal: reference is not a tree: 1c2769383f027befac5b75b6cedd25daf3bf4dcf
       
           /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:142:in `rescue in
           execute_command'
           /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:139:in
`execute_command'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:166:in `block
in executable'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:153:in
`target_git'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:148:in
checkout_commit' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:67:in download!'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:82:in block in download' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:157:in block in
ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:156:in ui_action'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in
download' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:108:in download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:75:in
download_request' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:154:in block in uncached_pod' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in in_tmpdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in
uncached_pod' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in
`download_source'

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:69:in
install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:557:in install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:508:in block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:507:in block in install_pod_sources' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in
install_pod_sources' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:249:in block in
download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:248:in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:157:in install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `

'
[ +187 ms] Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
[ ] Cloning into '/var/folders/35/7c585fqj58s1xtl93svqy_xh0000gn/T/d20200731-5606-i9uho2'...
fatal: reference is not a tree: 1c2769383f027befac5b75b6cedd25daf3bf4dcf

           [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no
platform was
specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform.

[ +4 ms] Error running pod install
[ +2 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
[ +10 ms] "flutter run" took 17,886ms.

#0 throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1 RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:569:7)

#2 FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:723:18)
#3 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#4 _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#5 _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#6 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#7 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#8 Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#9 _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
#10 _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
#11 RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#12 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#13 _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#14 _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#15 Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#16 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#17 Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#18 Future._asyncComplete. (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
#19 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#20 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#21 _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#22 _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
#23 _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#24 _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#25 _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#26 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


**Flutter Doctor**

seemants-MacBook-Pro:repos seemantsinha$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/seemantsinha/Documents/flutter
• Framework revision 8af6b2f (4 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
• Engine revision ee76268252
• Dart version 2.8.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/seemantsinha/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/seemantsinha/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.4, Build version 11E146
• CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 38.2.1
• Dart plugin version 183.6270
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• iPhone 11 Pro • BDF8B4F7-B661-49D6-BD82-70D364DEFB26 • ios •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)
```

Comment: Hi, did you find solution?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: To solve this I created new project updated all the packages and copy pasted my code into new project.

Comment: A good and consistent internet connection will help.

It downloads almost 1 GB of data.

Answer (score 9):

It just needs good internet speed as 1GB of data gets downloaded.

For me it took 30 minutes

Have patience

Answer (score 1):

Please retry.

I'm able to see the commit at https://github.com/google/boringssl/commit/1c2769383f027befac5b75b6cedd25daf3bf4dcf so likely it was a spurious networking issue.

Comment: It didn't work with slow internet(12Mb/s) which is not very small actually. It worked with 75Mb/s speed and took about 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

This issue mainly comes when **downloading** the required files by ios and if the internet connection is **slow**, you get this error